# PL/SQL Creating a table with indexes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL code:

```
    DROP TABLE TAB_PARAM;

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE TAB_PARAM
  (
     TABLE_OWNER  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     TABLE_NAME   VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     COLUMN_NAME  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     PATTERN VARCHAR2(1024),
     TYPE_METHODE VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
     SEPARATEUR VARCHAR2(20),
     ID VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TAB_PARAM PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) USING INDEX TABLESPACE IND_PARC_256M NOLOGGING
  )
  TABLESPACE TAB_PARC_256M NOLOGGING NOCACHE NOMONITORING NOPARALLEL';

commit;
END;
/
```

I don't understand the part :

```
CONSTRAINT PK_TAB_PARAM PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) USING INDEX TABLESPACE IND_PARC_256M NOLOGGING
```

Nor the part:

```
TABLESPACE TAB_PARC_256M NOLOGGING NOCACHE NOMONITORING NOPARALLEL';
```

I know that it is setting the ID as primary key of TAB_PARAM but then I do not get the index part.
Can anyone help me understand this code please?

Comment: check this https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32603462618660

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`create table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) or [constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180)? And why are you using `execute immediate` or any PL/SQL for this?

Comment: @AlexPoole : this is the code of someone else which I am trying to understand.

Comment: [Oracle 11.2 SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm)

Comment: The part that I don't understand is the `COMMIT` statement. Why is it there?

Comment: @mathguy - maybe because the code's author is more familiar with some other DBMS where DDL is transactional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you can create a table in a disposable way , for example you need to read data via sqlloader from file and insert in table , after that you will select all records from table . This operation doesnt need indexes and doesnt need primary key . Anyway it is always good to create primary key when you create a table and Oracle will create index for you . You can create more indexes whenever you want since the table was created . Now suppose you wanna update the table using **where** condition on a field who is not a primary key , it could be a better decision create an index on that field . In addition when you create indexes or table , you can associate tablespaces (created before) and could be good practice separate tablespaces for tables and indexes . All those operations are DDL Statements . In  Oracle you can check datafiles , tables and indexes with those queries `select * from dba_data_files; select * from dba_tables; select * from dba_indexes;`

Answer (score 2):

For primary key oracle implicitly creates unique index in table's tablespace.
This part  `USING INDEX TABLESPACE` allow us to indicate tablespace for this implicitly index.

`NOLOGGING` - data is modified with minimal logging (to mark new extents invalid and to record dictionary changes).

`NOCACHE` - Oracle doesn't  store blocks in the buffer cache.

`NOPARALLEL` - Parallel execution is not allowed on this table.(Default value)

`NOMONITORING` -  Disable statistics collection. Now is deprecated. There is other mechanism  to collect statistic

Comment: If the tablespace is not specified for an index, it is created in the *schema's default tablespace* - not necessarily that of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Edit. from oracle [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJACHGAB)

> Oracle Database uses an existing index if it contains a unique set of values before enforcing the primary key constraint. The existing
>   index can be defined as unique or nonunique. When a DML operation is
>   performed, the primary key constraint is enforced using this existing
>   index.

If there already index hitting the pk columns , oracle will used it, else then Oracle Database generates a unique index.

so you can create a primary key in oracle without an index if there was already index for that columns , specifying an index is for performance issue. The purpose of an index in a table is to 'read' the data faster.

From the [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm)

> An index is a schema object that contains an entry for each value that
>   appears in the indexed column(s) of the table or cluster and provides
>   direct, fast access to rows.

As for the TABLESPACE,  its where the database object exists, so when you create a table you specify in which tablespace you want it to exists. Read more here [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm)

As for NOLOGGING NOCACHE NOMONITORING, so the table not to be logged in redo logs or cached, also related to performance issue.

Comment: Yes but what does CONSTRAINT PK_TAB_PARAM PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME) USING INDEX TABLESPACE IND_PARC_256M NOLOGGING stands for?

Comment: to create a primary key on a table you use this statemetn `CONSTRAINT PK_TAB_PARAM PRIMARY KEY`  adding `USING INDEX` the column will have index. the `tablespace` to add where this table to be create. you can create a table without adding constraint @tabby

Comment: No, you can't have a primary key without an index. The `using index` clause is to specify non-default properties for the index.

Comment: One downvote from me - for the first sentence, "you can create a PK in Oracle without an index, specifying an index if for performance." 100% wrong.

Comment: You can create a PK without *explicitly* creating or referring to an index; but a PK is always backed by an index; [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJACHGAB) ("When you create a primary key constraint...")